# Android. Convert file from WAV to OGG

Tags: android, wav, audio-recording, ogg

searching throw the stack i got confused. So, **what is my problem:**

I'm using `AudioRecord` class to record some audio, here's the code:

```
AudioRecord record = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION, 
            SAMPLING_RATE,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            mBufferSize);
record.startRecording();

int read = 0;
while (mIsRecording) {
    read = record.read(mAudioBuffer, 0, mBufferSize);
    if ((read == AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION) ||
            (read == AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) ||
            (read <= 0)) {
        continue;
    }

    proceed();
    write(out);
}
```

After recording is completed, i'm converting this `.pcm` raw data from `AudioRecord` to `.wav`:

```
private void convertRawToWav() {
    File file_raw = new File(mFileNameRaw);
    if (!file_raw.exists()) { return; }
    File file_wav = new File(mFileNameWav);
    try {
        PcmAudioHelper.convertRawToWav(WavAudioFormat.mono16Bit(SAMPLING_RATE), file_raw, file_wav);
        if (handler != null) {
            handler.onRecordSuccess();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (handler != null) {
            handler.onRecordSaveError();
        }
    }
}
```

I need `.wav` format in future, because there is trim function in my application, copied from [Ringdroid](https://code.google.com/archive/p/ringdroid/) which doesn't support OGG format, therefor : **PLEASE DO NOT RECOMMEND ME TO RECORD AUDIO AS OGG ON THE FLY**

**MAIN ISSUE:**
Wav format is too heavy weight, and i need to convert it to smaller one, which is either MP3 or OGG. MP3 is patented, so it's not an option. What i need is:
**To convert `.wav` file to `.ogg` file so it's weight will be much smaller**

**What i found:**
[This library](https://github.com/nwertzberger/libogg-vorbis-android), but it only converts `.pcm` data to `.ogg` while recording, and i need to convert whole file after trimmiing it as `.wav`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/naman14/TAndroidLame) lame wrapper project.

Comment: Hi, thx for reply, but this is MP3 format, it's not an option for me, i need OGG only

Comment: Oh, sorry. So You can use ffmpeg wrapper like [this](https://github.com/lalongooo/ffmpeg4android_demo) with run command "ffmpeg -i audio.wav  -acodec libvorbis audio.ogg" or something like that.

Comment: in theory i can, i was poundering about it, and come to conclusion that integrate such a huge library for one function is overkill =(

Comment: Agree. Did You thought about simple zip/unzip wav files?

Answer (score 0):

Wav file is just a big header + PCM. All you need to do is remove the 44 bytes in the front of the WAV to get the PCM and use the code that you shared with us to convert to OGG.